# $\mu\left(\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}S_n\right)\leq\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu(S_n)$ for open intervals $S_n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Studying elementary Lebesgue integration theory, I want to prove that $$\mu\left(\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}S_n\right)\leq\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu(S_n)$$
when $\{S_n\subset\mathbb R:n=1,2,...\}$ is countable of which each set is an open interval and $\mu$ is the length function.

The author wrote that it's trivial and I think so too, writing rigorously seems not that simple for me. Maybe I can use the fact that the infinite union is also open, so it can be represented by disjoint, countable, open intervals $\{I_i\subset\mathbb R : j=1,2,...\}$, and the summation of $\mu(I_i)$ shoule be smaller(or equal) than $\mu(S_n)$ by intuition.

Could anyone give me some rigorous proof?

Comment: Ok before we help you, can you write out the proof for finite (rather than countable) unions?

Comment: @air Sorry for messy, but my approach was that

For finite, let $S_1, S_2, ... ,S_n$ are open intervals. If they are disjoint, two lengths are equal by definition of $\mu$. If not, there exists $S_i, S_j$ such that $c\in S_i\cap S_j$.

So instead of $S_i=(a_i,b_i), S_j=(a_j,b_j)$, we can consider $T_i=(a_i, c+\epsilon), T_j=(c-\epsilon,b_j)$(well, the order will be changed for other cases) so the LHS could be small.

Comment: Hmm I don't follow you exactly, but it's something like that (induction also works to show finite case). Now the hint for the countable case is: Give yourself a $\varepsilon >0$ of room, cover a compact set by a countable union of open intervals. Then by compactness you get a finite number of intervals also covering your compact set; hence you can apply the finite case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\left \{ S_n \right \}_n$, define $T_1=S_1$ and then $T_n=S_n\setminus \bigcup^{n-1} _{k=1}S_k$. Then the $T_n$ are disjoint intervals, $T_n\subseteq S_n$ and  $\bigcup^n_{k=1}S_n=\bigcup^n_{k=1}T_n$. Putting this together, we have

$\lambda (\bigcup^n_{k=1}S_n)=\lambda (\bigcup^n_{k=1}T_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda (T_n)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda (S_n)$. This true for each $\in \mathbb N$ sothe result follows.